# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chooseEntry' of undefined (while developing a chrome extension using fileSystem API)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am using chrome's fileSystem API to develop a chrome extension which needs to save a file in .txt format. I have the following code -

manifest.json -

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2, 
    "permissions": [{"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory"]}],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [
       {
        "matches": ["file:///index.html"],
        "css": ["css/style.css"],
        "js": ["js/app.js"]
       }
    ]
}
```

app.js -

```
(function () {
    var text = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
    var saveAsButton = document.getElementById("saveas");
    function errorHandler() {
        return null;
    }
    saveAsButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'saveFile'}, function(writableFileEntry) {  
            writableFileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                writer.onerror = errorHandler;
                writer.onwriteend = function(e) {
                    console.log('write complete');
                };
                writer.write(new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'}));    
            }, errorHandler);   
        }); 
    });
})();
```

index.html -

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>note-in-chrome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="saveas">SAVE AS</button>
        <div id="content" contenteditable="true" data-text="Enter text here"></div>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Whenever I click the SAVE AS button, a prompt to choose a file should open, but I get the following error - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chooseEntry' of undefined`.

Comment: `chrome.fileSystem` is for Chrome apps, not Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `chrome.fileSystem` API is available to [Chrome apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index), but not to [Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index).

Comment: What are available alternatives for storing, reading and writing files for an extension?

Comment: There are none. Extensions are intentionally limited in this regard.